# Iterate through result and find biggest value Msql table

Tags: php, mysql, database

i am trying to get the biggest number out of the results given by my query 
when i do

```
while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $retval2 ) )
        {
             echo "expiry= \"{$row['ps_expire']}\"";                                        
        }
```

its printing all the items. like expiry = "0"  expiry = "12356" .

What i want is to loop through all results > find the biggest > and then echo > expiry = "biggest number"

Comment: why not perform the logic directly in SQL by using the `max` aggregate function?

Comment: You have 1.2 M rows and you let PHP find it eh?

Comment: There is a dupe close for your `mysql_` library you are using. Please move to `mysqli` or `PDO`